# Hibernate query to Sql query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

My entity of product looks like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")

public class OrderEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "order_id")
   private Long id;

   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(
        name = "order_products",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", referencedColumnName = "order_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   )
   private Set<ProductEntity> products = new HashSet<>();
}
```

ProductEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class ProductEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
    private Set<OrderEntity> orders = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I want to get all orders where product name is equal to wanted value. And I write sql query to get result from database, but I cannot write hibernate query for Spring Data JPA.

My query for postgreSQL looks like this:

```
SELECT o.order_id, op.product_id, p.name
  FROM public.order o
  INNER JOIN public.order_products op
    ON p.order_id = op.product_id
  INNER JOIN public.product p
    ON op.product_id = p.id
  WHERE p.name = 'Foo';
```

And this query return me an id of order, product_id and name of product. And this works. But I didn't know how to write this question as spring query using @Query.

I need a metohod in my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {
    @Query("") <- place for my query in Hibernate sql
    List<OrderEntity> findAllByProductName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? The language is named HQL (or JPQL). Not Hibernate SQL. Read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql and try something. Your query is quite simple to write, if you take the time to read the documentation and examples, and try things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: (it returns full OrderEntity objects )

```
@Query("select  o from OrderEntity o join o.products prod where prod.name = :name")
List<OrderEntity> findAllByProductName(@Param("name") String name);
```

if you need fetch eager all data for products use : **....OrderEntity o join o.products...** in query instead of *OrderEntity o join o.products*

Answer (score 1):

This is a projection consisting of columns from many entties, so you would have to go for the Result Class strategy.

Basically, you create a POJO class with expected result fields an an equivalent constructor:

```
public class ResultClass{

    private Integer orderId;
    private Integer productId;
    private String name;

    public ResultClass(Integer orderId, Integer productId, String name){
        // set the fields
    }
}
```

Then you alter the query a bit:

```
SELECT new com.mypkg.ResultClass(o.order_id, op.product_id, p.name)
FROM public.order o
INNER JOIN public.order_products op
  ON p.order_id = op.product_id
INNER JOIN public.product p
  ON op.product_id = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'Foo';
```

And change the return type on the interface method:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderEntity, Long> {
    @Query("...") 
    List<ResultClass> findAllByProductName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand. I ask for query for get all orders where product name is equal to wanted value.

Comment: Mmm... ok in that case that is too trivial of a answer anyway.. please read through the documentation as @JB Nizet pointed out. But in the end if you would want get columns from multiple tables as in your question.. then hopefully my post would come in handy

Comment: This answer is wrong anyway. You're still using a SQL query, and not a JPQL one.